# How To Install Ubuntu 14.04 on HP Dynamic Smart Array b120i logical drive

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hp, raid

I've got some problems when trying to install ubuntu on hp proliant dl 160 gen8. I've got 3 logical drives in dynamic smart array controller, and on installation screen I see only physical drives. How to install it on logical volume? I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the b120i does not have stables drivers under Ubuntu/Debian yet - this issue is discussed at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/214703.

There is a PPA by HP (note these are not fully tested nor certified): https://launchpad.net/~hp-iss-team/+archive/ubuntu/hp-storage?field.series_filter=trusty

If you need something suitable for production (as we did), then you are going to have to install a raid controller that is supported such as a P4xx controller.

You can also not use the onboard controller in raid mode - use Sata and configure software RAID within Ubuntu - https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html#software-raid

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, HP has some of the software (the *Management Component Pack fpr ProLiant*, MCP) ready, as it is now offered at http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR.

Having some of it installed on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (Kernel 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP), I can confirm that at least `hplog` and `hpasmcli` provide usable output.